# Comparing effective dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2005

Wondering if there is a better why in  the WHERE clause of choosing records when you need to look at effective start and end dates?

Currently this how I've done it in the past on MS SQL Server. Just worried about the date and not the time. I'm using SQL Server 2005.

```
AND Convert(datetime, Convert(char(10), ep.EffectiveStartDate, 101))
   <= Convert(datetime, Convert(char(10), GetDate(), 101))
AND Convert(datetime, Convert(char(10), ep.EffectiveEndDate, 101))
   >= Convert(datetime, Convert(char(10), GetDate(), 101))
```

Answer (score 1):

That is terrible, take a look at [Only In A Database Can You Get 1000% + Improvement By Changing A Few Lines Of Code](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/only-in-a-database-can-you-get-1000-impr) to see how you can optimize this since that is not sargable

Also check out [Get Datetime Without Time](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Get_Datetime_Without_Time) and [Query Optimizations With Dates](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Query_Optimizations_With_Dates)

Answer (score 1):

@Darren Kopp - you can use

```
set @date2 = '20201001'
```

this will let you lose the cast.

footndale - you can use date arithmetic to remove the time as well.  Something like

```
select dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0)
```

to get today's date (without the time).  I believe this is more efficient than casting back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

@Darren Kopp

Be carefull with BETWEEN, check out [How Does Between Work With Dates In SQL Server?](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-does-between-work-with-dates-in-sql-)

Answer (score 0):

```
AND DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()) + 1 > ep.EffectiveStartDate
AND DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()) < ep.EffectiveEndDate
```

I think you will find that these conditions offer the best performance possible. This will happily utilize indexes.

I am also very sure that this is right and will give the right data. No further calculation of dates without time portions is needed.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
ep.EffectiveStartDate BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
```

where you would do something like

```
declare @date1 datetime, @date2 datetime;  
set @date1 = cast('10/1/2000' as datetime)  
set @date2 = cast('10/1/2020' as datetime)
```

Comment: This isn't even close to what he's asking for. Where is `EffectiveEndDate`?